# What objective circumstances would preclude using a return value also as a diagnostic?

Tags: c, return-value, diagnostics

I was going through Linaro ODP framework and saw this code snippet,

```
static int find_block(const char *name, uint32_t *index)
{
    uint32_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, odp_shm_tbl->block[i].name) == 0) {
            /* found it */
            if (index != NULL)                                                                                                                         
                *index = i;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here, Instead of updating `*index`, We can return the value of `i` to achieve the same thing like below.

```
static int find_block(const char *name)
{
    uint32_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, odp_shm_tbl->block[i].name) == 0) {
            /* found it */
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Apart from taste, style and coding guidelines -- could there be any objective reasons why one must choose one and cannot choose the other?

Comment: The function already returns a boolean result. How else than by pointer argument would you pass another value to the caller?

Comment: You would likely return the index value, or something like -1 for "not found". Then you need to branch in your code, depending on the returned value. This is what many UNIX system calls do.

Comment: This apparently is a function with only internal linkage (see the `static`). Have a look at the code calling it, that might explain the choice.

Comment: "better" is a matter of opinion in this case. In a vacuum, there's nothing wrong with either approach. One or the other might fit certain local code patterns though, making its conversion out of place in a larger project. Regardless, as a matter of opinion it becomes off topic for SO.

Comment: What is unclear in question? Why it has been put on hold?

Comment: I had this exact situation come up in a small personal project recently, where I needed to return a `boolean` but also update a value.  I ended up doing the same as the code snippet above (passing in a pointer to an `int` and returning `boolean`).  I wasn't sure if it was hackish or not, so I don't see why asking for clarification here deserves downvotes.

Comment: @HellmarBecker: It strongly depends on the caller. It might be useful `*index` is only changed on success.

Comment: @tijko: Because that is asking for opinion and no context is given. Depending on the caller, both versions might behave differently.

Comment: Reasonable question, and not entirely opinion based, so close vote is mistaken -- in my opinion ;-).  One can discuss the (objective!) pro and con reasons, obviously, as is happening in comments. I have seen so many worse questions today that I'm happy to see and discuss this one.

Comment: In the first function, the returned index is an unsigned integer. There is no possible way to have it return a negative value to signal failure. The second function merely changes the type used to int, so it will behave unpredictably if the index to find is superior to INT_MAX.

Comment: @SirDarius Good point. This seems to be a kernel code snippet, and the API/data structures are locked in; this precludes abusing the index as a diagnostic (the set of possible indices encompasses all possible values of the data type), and answers the question right there. (Note: This is not the least opinion based.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider the original question that was posted was asking if one style had advantages over the other or one style is "better" than the other. Your edits really changed the nature of the question and may or may not be aligned with what the poster was asking. Given your edits I agree that the question is a bit less oriented towards being opinion, but it certainly is not clear that the edits you made are valid for what was being sought.

Comment: @mah Well, I tried to "see the good part" of the question in the light of the SO criteria and focus on it. (The discussion very nicely chisled out the underlying rationale! I learned something.) Why not be constructive. What the original poster had in mind only the gods know, and it's fairly uninteresting to the world at large (with all due respect, JagsVG ;-) ).

Comment: One could have the function return a uint32_t instead of an int. Then checking the return value against ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS  tests whether the block was found.

Comment: @FredK Hm, another good spot -- obviously (after you pointed it out)  the set of possible indices does *not* encompass all possible values! So it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I understand you intend to be constructive, but edits on SO shouldn't be made such that the new content is different from the original intent. A help page entry about edits includes _to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it_. As you indicate in your comment above, the intent of the question cannot be reasonably discerned. That makes it difficult to apply even clarification editing since one cannot know what it is that needs to be clarified in the first place. Just food for thought. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit is the help page I referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the question in the title:

- You cannot use the return value also as diagnostic if all values in the range of the return type are to be considered valid (in the sense of non-error, non-diagnostic) return values.
- Using magic values instead of boolean standard values as error reporting (which is needed if these standard values could be valid results of the function) creates a (slightly) leaky abstraction.

---

What you see is used when one wants to have multiple return values, or even more likely conditionally many return values.

Your assumption ...

> Here, Instead of updating `*index`, We can return the value of `i` to achieve the same thing like below.

... is wrong:

`*index` is an unsigned integer, thus having the range 0 to 2^(32-1) as valid values. **Each of these values seems to be a valid index value**. Thus you have 2^32 **valid** results.

In order to indicate failure, without using the "trick" with multiple return values, you'd need to return a value that has no valid meaning, and is thus able to carry the special meaning as indication of a failure. Assuming there is only the indication of failure (and no detailed error value) you'd have 1 **invalid** result value.

This leaves you with 2^32 + 1 **possible** result values, which doesn't fit in an 32 bit unsigned integer (and also doesn't fit in the `int` your example uses).

A possible solution would be to extend the range of the return value, e.g. by using 64 bit unsigned integers. Then you could use value 2^32 (which is outside the range of valid values) to indicate failure:

```
#define MAGIC_FAILURE (((uint64_t) 1) << 32)
static uint64_t find_block(const char *name)
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, odp_shm_tbl->block[i].name) == 0) {
            /* found it */
            return i;
        }
    }
    // return magic value indicating failure
    return MAGIC_FAILURE;
}
```

I'd consider this bad practice, because to understand the function you also need to have the magic value in your head. Also consider debugging this function (or some caller): It's far easier to examine the return value of the original function (which returned data via pointer) and see a boolean value (which one is used to) instead of having to demangle the return value of above function to decide whether it's valid or not.

One final note: In this case though, I'd have gone with a different approach:

```
static uint32_t find_block(const char *name)
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, odp_shm_tbl->block[i].name) == 0) {
            /* found it */
            return i;
        }
    }
    return ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS;
}
```

One could use this because, as the implementation of the loop indicates, not every 32 bit unsigned integer is a valid index (this leaving space for a magic number indicating failure). Using an obviously related constant is a better choice than some random magic value.

Though do also consider the call site:

```
uint32_t index;
if (! find_block("foo", &index)) {
  // OMG
}
// all nice
```

Here you have only the function name, which is all you need when you want to find a block by its name.

```
int32_t index = find_block("foo");
if (index == ODP_CONFIG_SHM_BLOCKS) {
  // OMG
}
// all nice
```

Here on the other hand you need two "things" in order to find a block by its name: the function name as well as the magic value. This could be considered a leak in the abstraction.